# FROM_UNIXTIME(o.created,'%d-%m-%Y') in where clause gives error

Tags: datetime

I am working on Drupal 6. while executing  query when I add
`and FROM_UNIXTIME(o.created,'%d-%m-%Y') <  '".arg(3)."'";`
to WHERE clause it doesn't return result.
i have tried by using same query in MySQL Query Browser it returns result.
so I am confused how to pass above condition in WHERE clause,
as I am passing 31-10-2012 in arg(3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to escape the percent sign with another, i.e.,

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(o.created,'%%d-%%m-%%Y')
```

Also make sure you use parameter replacement rather than injecting strings directly into the query; you're not protected from SQL injection at the moment.

That would be something like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(o.created,'%%d-%%m-%%Y') < '%s'";
$result = db_query($sql, arg(3));
```

Comment: i am using ($conditions .= " and FROM_UNIXTIME(o.created,'%%d-%%m-%%Y') >'".arg(2). "'" ;) and at end i append $conditions to my query. n hope it prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: It won't prevent SQL injection unless you sanitise the argument, the method you're currently using means you're definitely susceptible to an injection attack

Answer (score 1):

In this question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149472/addexpression-and-from-unixtime-format, I asked the same question but in relation to Drupal 7 and the addExpression method of the SelectQuery object.

Problem Code:

```
$query->addExpression('FROM_UNIXTIME(w.submitted, "%Y-%m")', 'Date');
```

Solution (reverse the quotes):

```
$query->addExpression("FROM_UNIXTIME(w.submitted, '%Y-%m')", 'Date');
```